# Google Tag Manger / Inject iframe in DIV / Works in Preview Mode but not in production

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to insert an iframe into a div with the UTM parameters of the parent URL. In order to achieve this, I have a simple trigger based on page URL like this:
[image]

and then for the tag, I have this:
[image]

The code is the following, I have removed the iframe url:

```
​<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('insert iframe');
 var iframeurl = 'xxx';
 var params = window.location.search.replace('?','');

 var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

 iframe.setAttribute('src', iframeurl +'&'+ params);
 iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
 iframe.setAttribute('height', '700px');
 iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
 iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
 iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
 iframe.style.border = '0';

getRef = document.getElementById("contest_iframe");
parentDiv = getRef.parentNode;
parentDiv.insertBefore(iframe, getRef);
 

</script>
```

When I execute the code in my browser console, it works. When I execute the Tag Assistant it works but when I try it in production, it doesn't work, the tag is not fired.

This is what I see in the assistant:
[image]

Everything seems to be ok, I don't understand why it doesn't work, I probably have missed something somewhere.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making it an anonymous, self-executing function?

```
(function(){
  //your code
})();
```

Comment: Hi Ramon, thanks, I have tried your suggestion but it doesnt solve the problem.